# Name for number of elements of order (1 or) 2 in an abelian group

Tags: terminology, gr.group-theory

Let $G$ be an (additive) abelian group.  Is there a concise, standard term for the order of the kernel $K$ of the endomorphism $g\mapsto 2g$?  Or alternatively, for the index of $K$?

Comment: Order of 2-torsion of G.

Comment: Thanks!  Now I need to type some more because the software won't let me post a comment as short as "Thanks!" 