# Random walk is to diffusion as self-avoiding random walk is to ...?

Tags: discrete-geometry, pr.probability, ergodic-theory, markov-chains

One can view a random walk as a discrete process whose continuous
analog is diffusion.
For example, discretizing the heat diffusion equation
(in both time and space) leads to random walks.
Is there a natural continuous analog of discrete self-avoiding walks?
I am particularly interested in self-avoiding polygons,
i.e., closed self-avoiding walks.

I've only found reference
(in Madras and Slade,
*The Self-Avoiding Walk*, p.365ff)
to continuous analogs of "weakly self-avoiding walks"
(or "self-repellent walks") which discourage but
do not forbid self-intersection.

I realize this is a vague question,
reflecting my ignorance of the topic.
But perhaps those knowledgeable could point me to the
the right concepts.  Thanks!

**Addendum**.
[Schramm–Loewner evolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schramm%E2%80%93Loewner_evolution) is the answer.  It is the conjectured scaling limit of the self-avoiding walk and several other related stochastic processes.  Conjectured in low dimensions,
proved in high dimensions, as pointed out by Yuri and Yvan.  Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Random knots :)

Comment: See this old blog post: http://www.maa.org/mathland/mathtrek_11_3.html for a *very* gentle introduction. This is about the extent of my knowledge though...

Comment: @Tom Boardman: Yes, that work of Sumners and Whittington on random knots is fascinating! Whether knot theory is analogous to diffusion in this situation is not clear to me. I am seeking a continuous theory that parallels and informs the discrete.

Comment: This might be off-topic for this site, but you may also want to look at polymer physics books to see how physicists treat problems involving lots of long chains of molecules.  (Surprisingly often, self-avoidance turns out to be unimportant to the properties of polymeric materials.)  There's an article by Tom McLeish in a recent Physics Today that serves as a teaser to the field http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.2970211 (it may be easier to find if you go to your institution's physics library and browse through recent issues), and  a good introductory book is _Introduction to Polymer Physics_ by Doi.

Comment: @jc: Thanks for the connection.  I can see that many of the references in the Lawler paper to which Yuri pointed me are to journals such as *J. Statist. Phys.*, *J. Stat. Mech. Theory Exp.*, *J. Math Phys.*, *Phys. Let.*, etc.  I may be in over my head, but it should be a fun swim!

Comment: There is no direct analog because for ordinary random walk, you don't need to know the past to go forward in time. To go forward in time in a self-avoiding walk, you need to know the past, so you know what to avoid. This means that there is no differential equation form of the process, which is what I think you wanted.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In 2D the scaling limit is believed to be SLE with parameter 8/3. This was conjectured by Lawler, Schramm and Werner and, to the best of my knowledge, still remains open.

Comment: SLE = ?  Sorry for my ignorance...

Comment: SLE=Schramm–Loewner evolution, see, e.g., http://arxiv.org/abs/0712.3256

Comment: Thank you! [Interesting: "Thank you!" is too short a comment for MO! So I had to add this pointless parenthetical remark to post.]

Comment: @Joseph: to make it longer I usually add some !s or do more spacing between "Thank" and "you!"

Comment: Well, and in dimensions $5$ and higher, the scaling limit is again Brownian motion, as proved long ago by Hara and Slade.

Comment: @Joseph and @Wadim, re short comments: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/18263/name-for-number-of-elements-of-order-1-or-2-in-an-abelian-group

Comment: Cool!      ${}$

Comment: SLE        ${}$

Answer (score 3):

For SLE see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schramm%E2%80%93Loewner_evolution

Comment: Ah, thank you!!  It may be that Schramm–Loewner evolution is the theory I seek...

Comment: @Joseph: "SLE" could be too short for an answer! :-)